# Publish RPM to remote YUM repository with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm, yum

In our team we build RPM file containing our app, and then we have a bash/cURL script to publish it to the remote YUM repository. Essentially it is a HTTP POST with form data:

```
curl ${curl_opts} -F "rpm=@$RPM;type=application/x-redhat-package-manager"
```

Now I want to replace this script with the SBT, since it's inconvenient to have it from deployment perspective. I've tried to find some SBT plugin that can handle this for me, but to no avail. Is there such a thing?

P.S. I guess, another approach would be to perform such HTTP POST from SBT directly, but that would be the other question.

Comment: I believe you can call curl directly from sbt via http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html Then you can make it a custom task or even make your very own plugin.

Comment: That would imply curl is installed on that machine, which is not necessarily the case. I'd like to minimize the build system dependencies to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SBT Native Packager (RPM)](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/rpm.html) to generate the RPM and configure [sbt-package-courier](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/deployment.html) to deploy to your repository.

In your plugins.sbt file add:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.4")
addSbtPlugin("io.sysa" % "sbt-package-courier" % "0.2.0")
```

Then for publishing:

```
enablePlugins(RpmArtifactoryDeployPlugin)
rpmArtifactoryUrl in Rpm := "https://repo.acme.corp/artifactory"
rpmArtifactoryCredentials in Rpm := Some(Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2"/ ".credentials"))
rpmArtifactoryRepo in Rpm := "rpm-repo"
rpmArtifactoryPath in Rpm := s"pool/${packageName.value}"
publish in Rpm := (rpmArtifactoryPublish in Rpm).value
```

And finally

```
sbt rpm:publish
```

I believe you already have done packaging part.